# Python: 2D List Statistics : Finding Min, Max, Sum

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, min

I'm having some trouble trying to use functions in order to calculate the min, max, and sum of a list.
The list is randomly generated and the user is able to select how many values are present in the list.
Could someone help me figure out how to create a function using both a tempList and a tempdim(temporary dimension)?

I have a code to make the dimensions and the random list, I feel like I have a pretty good structure of the program.. I just can't figure out how to make the function code.

This is what I have so far...

```html
import random

MINRAND = 1
MAXRAND = 1000


def main():
    dimensions = int(input("How large do you want your square 2D array? "))
    numbers = [[] for i in range(dimensions)]
    generateList(numbers, dimensions)
    printList(numbers, dimensions)
    print("2-D List Highest Element is: ", findHighest(tempList))
    print("2-D List Lowest Element is: ", findLowest(tempList))
    print("2-D List Sum is: ", sum2Dlist(tempList))

def findHighest(tempList, tempdim):

def findLowest(tempList, tempdim):


def sum2Dlist(tempList, tempdim):


def generateList(tempList, tempdim):
    for row in range(tempdim):
        for col in range(tempdim):
            tempList[row].append(random.randint(MINRAND, MAXRAND))


def printList(templist, tempdim):
    for row in range(tempdim):
        for col in range(tempdim):
            print(format(templist[row][col], '6d'), end=" ")
        print()


# Call the main function
main()
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: `min`, `max`, and `sum` are all built-in python functions that work on lists. Is there some reason those are insufficient?